# Bash Script accepting a number, then printing a set of int from 0 to the number entered

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a bash script that accepts a number from the keyboard, and then prints a set of integers from 0 to the number entered. I can't figure out how to do it at all.
This is my code:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    echo -n "Enter a color: "
    read user_answer

    for (( $user_answer = $user_answer; $user_answer>0; $user_answer--))

            echo $user_answer

    fi
done

exit
```

The error I'm recieving is:
number_loop: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
number_loop: line 10:`         echo $user_answer'

Comment: you are missing do for matching done

Comment: Take alook at www.shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1):

Assign a separate variable in order to use increment/decrement operators. `$user_answer=$user_answer` will always be true and it will throw an error when trying to use decrement. Try the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
 do
  echo -n "Enter a color: "
  read user_answer

  for (( i=$user_answer; i>0; i-- ))
   do
      echo $i
  done
done
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `do` statement between your `for` and the `echo`.

Comment: for loop is correct . Check this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm checking it out now. Definitely love your guy's support.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` has many options to write numbers. What you seem to be trying to do is easiest done with `seq`:

```
seq $user_answer -1 0
```

If you want to use your loop, you have to insert a `; do` and replace the `fi` with `done`, and replace several `$user_answer`:

```
for (( i = $user_answer; i>0; i--)); do

        echo $i

done
```

(btw: I assumed that you wanted to write the numbers in reverse order, as you are going backwards in your loop. Forwards is even easier with `seq`:

```
seq 0 $user_input
```

)

Answer (score 0):

This is where a **c-style loop** works particularly well:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i = 1; i <= $1; i++)); do
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
done

exit 0
```

**Example**

```
$ bash simplefor.sh 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Note:** `<=` is used as the for loop test so it `10` it iterates `1-10` instead of `0-9`.

In your particular case, iterating from `$user_answer` you would want:

```
for (( i = $user_answer; i > 0; i--)); do
        echo $i
done
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `i < $(($1+1))` instead of `i <= $1` ?

Comment: It kept me from using `<=`. Six to one, half-dozen to another. Updated anyway.

Comment: That was a bit of **tongue-in-cheek** humor. Either way works, and I generally do use the `<=`, but in this case just adjusted the index itself instead.

Comment: That's strange. That's how I generated the output. You can test again by copying `for ((i=1; i<=10;i++)); do printf "%2d really works\n" $i; done` right into the command line and see the result. **Oh** for my first answer, you have to give the number on the command line. `$1` means the first **positional parameter** to the program (i.e. the **first argument**). So copy the script to say: `simpleloop.sh`, then run `bash simpleloop.sh 10`...

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is a bash internal command, so it doesn't fork a new process.

The `seq` command has a nice, one-line syntax.

To get the best of the twos, you can use the `{ .. }` syntax:

```bash
eval echo {1..$answer}
```